# How to upload a web site

Tags: web-hosting, ftp, uploading

So I have been experimenting with web design for the last year and I was always viewing the web pages locally on my machine. Now a friend wants to create a web page and I have already designed everything but i wouldn't know how to upload the files to make it run.

He has registered the domain on Domains by Proxy and he gave me some passwords that they sent him. When I visit the web page www.myfriendsdomain.com I get the godaddy.com message that this is domain is parked for free. When I log in the DBP website I don't see any relative link for uploading files.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with DBP, but it doesn't sound like *hosting*, which is what you need to have in order to upload a site. A domain without hosting is like a street address without a house - you need to build your home (web hosting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend needs to give you FTP access to the web hosting space.  You can then upload the files using a free FTP client such as FileZilla.

Comment: So in this case i guess the web hosting is done by go daddy?

Comment: @user926652: You need to find out from your friend if he purchased web hosting with GoDaddy or anyone else.

Comment: @user92652 It would appear that way

Comment: Ok i guess i understood what happened here the hosting company is godaddy. I marked your answer as correct because you were the fastest one..Thanx everybody for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

according to their support you just need to upload your website into the root directory. Also make sure you delete their index.html file if you don't replace it with your own.

FYI, [godaddy has a good support section in their website](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=US&ie=UTF-8&source=android-browser&q=godaddy+how+to+upload+my+website) . Definitely read through it as it tells you how to do everything.

Comment: Can you please send me the link where it says that on their support because i cant find it? Thanx in advance